# Перевод из String в PublicKey

Tags: java, android

Имею переменную типа String: `who_open_key = "OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=e6gfe73g3fg6 ... 2a56c3,publicExponent=10001}"`

По факту это открытый ключ шифра RSA но записанный в String. Соответственно для шифровки мне нужно перевести его из String в тип PublicKey. Пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
private PublicKey restorePublic_Who(byte key[]) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(key);
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    }

...

try {
     PublicKey public_key_who = restorePublic_Who(who_open_key.getBytes());
}catch (Exception e) {                                  
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     Log.d("TAG123", "Ключи шифрования не были извлечены");
}
...
```

В exeption выбрасывает это:

> 08-09 15:43:22.892 12921-12921/com.example.jack.myapplication W/System.err: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0890ba:ASN.1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:WRONG_TAG
>   08-09 15:43:22.892 12921-12921/com.example.jack.myapplication W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0c0890ba:ASN.1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:WRONG_TAG

Что я делаю не так? Как мне перевести String в PublicKey?

P.S. ошибка logcat такая:

```
08-09 16:02:10.876 25488-25502/com.example.jack.myapplication E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xeb0e90d0
```

Comment: А не нужно предварительно вырезать сам ключ из строки? Что-то мне подсказывает, что "OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=" и т.д. - это лишнее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У меня устойчивое чувство, что я изобрёл велосипед, но оно работает:

```
String key = "OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=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,publicExponent=00010001}";

String modulus = key.substring(key.indexOf("=") + 1, key.indexOf(","));
String exponent = key.substring(key.lastIndexOf("=") + 1, key.indexOf("}"));

BigInteger M = new BigInteger(modulus, 16);
BigInteger E = new BigInteger(exponent, 16);

try {
    RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(M, E);
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pub = factory.generatePublic(spec);
}
catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {}
catch(InvalidKeySpecException e) {}
```